# Android Studio UI error after ./studio.sh

Tags: linux, android-studio, archlinux

After `./studio.sh` in terminal I get this window and can't follow setup wizard

[Broken UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6HS4.png)

I also try to install via AUR package but still got that error

My OS is `Arch Linux 64bit` and I'm using `KDE`

Comment: hello, I had similar problem on Ubuntu. Try the latest version or search or the older one. It may be issue with Google's installer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with latest beta version and older one, but that issue still happened

Comment: add new environment like xfce and try on it. it might be kde issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by install and use openjdk 8 instead of openjdk 7